# Log4Net offline DB Support

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net

I am developing an asp.net web application and want to log my exceptions into SQL DB. For this I am using Log4Net AdoNetAppender to log info into SQL DB, now the problem occurs when the DB goes offline. Log4Net  doesn't persist the log messages. So all messages get lost while the DB was offline, is there any way to retain the messages until the DB comes online and then log all the messages to DB once it become available. Although by using **reconnectonerror value="True"**  it starts logging again when DB is available but all intermediate messages while DB was offline are not logged.

Or there exist any other approach to log exceptions in Db with offline support.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing with helps you out of the box with this. You can always log to a file (keep the last week or so) and the database. If for some reason there is a gab in the logging you can fallback on the file.

If you want the behavior you describe you can always implement your own appender. Let is inherrit from the adonetappender and add your failover code. However keep in mind that you do not want to create an appender which eat all your memory...